# Batch apex class to update a field

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

The requirement is i need to write a Batch Apex Class to update Case status field to close when related tickets field status is closed. The update of status should be after 7 days of all the tickets related to a case are closed.

There are two objects who appropriate fields are

- Case (Object)      : status (Field)
- Ticket__C (Object) : GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c (Field).

> Note: Ticket__c Has a look up to the Case. So, a case can have multiple tickets but a ticket can only be associated to one case.

The class i have written should do the following steps

1. Get all the records of a case whose status is Open, Breached and Escalated.
2. List all the tickets associated to a case i.e CaseId = Ticket.Id
3. check for all Ticket__c associated to case whose status = closed (if the status of ticket != closed,come out of the loop. Because a case cannot be closed when any of its tickets status #!= closed)
4. if all the tickets of a case are closed, update status of a case to close after 7 days of ticket status == close using lastmodifielddate.

Below is the code i could write so far. I need help in modifying the code to make it work

```
global class CloseCaseBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{
  private Boolean allClosedTickets;
  private String query = 'Select Id, Status from Case WHERE Status = \'Open\' OR ' +
         'Status = \'Escalated\' OR' +
         'Status = \'Breached\''; // Getting case records whose status is open (or) escalated (or) Breached

  // method implemented from Schedulable interface
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    Database.executebatch(this); 
    }
  //Start Method which retrieves the records of case
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)  {
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
         System.debug('checkcase---' + query); //debugging
      }
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    List<Case> casestatusOEB = (List<Case>)scope; //List of cases
    System.debug('checkcase---' +scope); //debugging
    Set<ID> caseIDs = new Set<ID>(); // Setting Case id
    Map<ID,List<Ticket__c>> CaseID_TicketList = new Map<ID,List<Ticket__c>>(); //mapping case id to ticket__C
      for(case getCaserecords : casestatusOEB) {
             caseID.put(getCaserecords.id);  // Setting the case ID 
      }

  }
  List<Ticket__c> ticket = [Select ID, LastModifiedDate , GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c,
                             GLOBAL_Goal__c from Ticket__c 
                             where GLOBAL_Goal__c in :caseIDs]; // Listing tickets whose id = Caseid
      for(Ticket__c tkt : ticket) {
      System.debug('new list of ticket' +ticket); 
          if (tkt.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'closed')
              caseIDs.add(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);    
      } 

  List<Ticket__c> tkt = new List<Ticket__c>();
      if(CaseID_TicketList.containsKey(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c)){
          tkt = CaseID_TicketList.get(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);
      } 
          else {
          tkt.add(ticket);                }
          CaseID_TicketList.put(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c,tkList);
          // Map case & ticket
          }


  allClosedTickets;  // validation to check ticket status. if status != closed come out of the loop 
      for (Ticket__c ticket: scase) { // Ticket loop
         System.debug('checkcase---' +ticket); //debugging
      // save LastModified date of the highest date
          if (ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c != 'closed') {
             allClosedTickets = false;
          //caseIDs.add(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);   // case ID of current Records.
          }

    }

          if (allClosedTickets = true) { // all closed so Case can be closed
          // if lastModifiedDate greater than 7 days then
          // add CaseId to casesToUpdate


  List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();  // getting total tickets of that case and closedticket and if(closedTickets == totalTickets) and all of them are closed. then update the case status to closed after 7 days of a tickets status = closed based on lastmodifieddate >7

      for (Id caseID : caseIDs) {

          Integer totalTickets = CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID).size();
          Integer closedTickets = 0;
              for(Ticket__c ticket : CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID)){ 
                  if(ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'Closed'){
                  closedTickets++;
                  }
              }
                  if(closedTickets == totalTickets) {
                  casesToUpdate.add(new Case(Id = caseID, Status= 'Closed'));
                  }
              }

                  if(!casesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                  update casesToUpdate; //updating case status after 7 days"" 7 days logic is missing
                  }
      }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }

  }
```

Comment: What is it that's not working with this code? Will it not save? Does it not do what you think it should?

Comment: i have to set Case ID and get the list of tickes associated to the case 2. using boolean allClosedtickets to check ticket__c status =closed or != closed 3. if all the tickets associated to case are not closed come out of the loop and if all the tickets are closed then update case status after 7 days of all its tickets being closed   
These are the problems i am having and i have left small comments in the code. i need some one to correct my code and add lastmodifieddate on ticket > 7 then close the case

Comment: I appreciate that you are here for assistance, but it appears that you just want the community to do your work for you.

Comment: @Developer if you would have think by this time you might have finished this code. Please try and code yourself that will give you more knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of misplaced brackets and there is still at least one missing method (or class member/variable), `getCaseRecords`. As written this code won't compile, but this might get you started.

```
global class CloseCaseBatch implements Database.Batchable <sObject> , Schedulable {

    private Boolean allClosedTickets;
    private String query = 'Select Id, Status from Case WHERE Status = \'Open\' OR ' +
        'Status = \'Escalated\' OR' +
        'Status = \'Breached\''; // Getting case records whose status is open (or) escalated (or) Breached

    // method implemented from Schedulable interface
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executebatch(this);
    }

    //Start Method which retrieves the records of case
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        System.debug('checkcase---' + query); //debugging
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List <sObject> scope) {
        List <Case> casestatusOEB = (List <Case> ) scope; //List of cases
        System.debug('checkcase---' + scope); //debugging
        Set <ID> caseIDs = new Set <ID> (); // Setting Case id
        Map <ID, List <Ticket__c>> CaseID_TicketList = new Map <ID, List <Ticket__c>> (); //mapping case id to ticket__C
        for (Case getCaserecords : casestatusOEB) {
            caseID.put(getCaserecords.id); // Setting the case ID 
        }


        List <Ticket__c> ticket = [Select ID, LastModifiedDate, GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c,
                                        GLOBAL_Goal__c from Ticket__c
                                        where GLOBAL_Goal__c in : caseIDs
                                    ]; // Listing tickets whose id = Caseid

        for (Ticket__c tkt: ticket) {
            System.debug('new list of ticket' + ticket);
            if (tkt.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'closed')
                caseIDs.add(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);
        }

        List <Ticket__c> tkt = new List <Ticket__c> ();
        if (CaseID_TicketList.containsKey(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c)) {
            tkt = CaseID_TicketList.get(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);
        } else {
            tkt.add(ticket);
        }
        CaseID_TicketList.put(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c, tkList);
        // Map case & ticket



        allClosedTickets; // validation to check ticket status. if status != closed come out of the loop 
        for (Ticket__c ticket: scase) { // Ticket loop
            System.debug('checkcase---' + ticket); //debugging
            // save LastModified date of the highest date
            if (ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c != 'closed') {
                allClosedTickets = false;
                //caseIDs.add(ticket.GLOBAL_Goal__c);   // case ID of current Records.
            }

        }

        if (allClosedTickets = true) { // all closed so Case can be closed
            // if lastModifiedDate greater than 7 days then
            // add CaseId to casesToUpdate


            List <Case> casesToUpdate = new List <Case> (); // getting total tickets of that case and closedticket and if(closedTickets == totalTickets) and all of them are closed. then update the case status to closed after 7 days of a tickets status = closed based on lastmodifieddate>7

            for (Id caseID: caseIDs) {

                Integer totalTickets = CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID).size();
                Integer closedTickets = 0;
                for (Ticket__c ticket: CaseID_TicketList.get(caseID)) {
                    if (ticket.GLOBAL_Ticket_Status__c == 'Closed') {
                        closedTickets++;
                    }
                }
                if (closedTickets == totalTickets) {
                    casesToUpdate.add(new Case(Id = caseID, Status = 'Closed'));
                }
            }

            if (!casesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                update casesToUpdate; //updating case status after 7 days"" 7 days logic is missing
            }
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mark, for the starters i am not sure about the logic i wrote behind setting case ids and retrieving the  list of tickets associated to that particular case .And close case after 7 days of all the tickets being closed logic is missing as i have problem understanding how to write that. if you can help me on that your help will be much appreciated

Comment: I suggest that you reach out to the person who wrote this `CloseCaseBatch` class for assistance in implementing your requirements. That individual can probably also instruct you on Apex as it appears they were skilled at it and are familiar with your use case.

Comment: @MarkPond well said. Developer you need to seek the help of the one who wrote this code for you or where you taken this code from...

Comment: Mark, i am the one who wrote this code. I am newbie and needed help in making changes to the code. That is the reason i pointed out the weak areas in the code

Comment: As I also asked on the question... what part of your code is not working? Help us help you.